# Jasper Report arabic query problem

Tags: java, internationalization, jasper-reports, reportviewer, arabic

I'm trying to make a report in jasper the report query contains this where statement

```
where payment='شيك'
```

when I try to run the report using the JRViewer300 I got the following exception

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRExpresssionEvalException : Error evaluating expression...
```

When I change the where statement to

```
where payment='cheque'
```

the report runs without any problem. So what is all this about?

Thanks

Comment: What about double quote?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that the database is set to work with UNICODE encoding, In Java you need to escape the input string (treat special chars) and turn the encoding to UTF-8 ( or 16) Check [this](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html#escapeSql%28java.lang.String%29) out.

...and also try this:

exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.CHARACTER_ENCODING, "UTF-8");

Comment: @Feras Odeh, this does the escaping, however, you need your DB Vendor driver to be configured to support an appropriate charset . I do not know who is your JDBC vendor, but probably you need to configure the driver to "set client_encoding to
iso-8859-8" in your case.

Comment: I don't think it is an encoding problem as I can insert arabic chars into datbase without any problem.as for my sql I but the UTF-8 encoding in the connection URL

Comment: don't you do the insert on the same (URL) connection?